# probability of distinct phone numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory

the first three digits of a university telephone exchange area 452. if all the sequences of the remaining four digits are equally likely, what is the probabikity that a randomly selected university phone number contains seven distinct digits?

Attempt:

Now there are two ways i am looking at this. First off the size of the total sample space is $10^7$. With that out of the way, i am i terpreting the question as saying that 452 have to be at the beginning of my phone number. In which case there would be $(3)(2)(1) $ ways of selecting those digits, now the other four digits can be selected $(7)(6)(5)(4) $ ways. Therefore:  $$\frac {(3)(2)(1) +(7)(6)(5)(4)}{10^7} $$

Now the other thing i considered is perhaps the 452 does not need to be at the beginning then there would be $(10)(9)... (4) $ distinct phone numbers and this would be divided by $10^7$.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First off the size of the total sample space is $10^7$.

Not if the first three digits are fixed as `452` and only the remaining four can vary.

> With that out of the way, i am i terpreting the question as saying that 452 have to be at the beginning of my phone number. In which case there would be (3)(2)(1) ways of selecting those digits,

No. There is only *one* way `452` can be selected.

> now the other four digits can be selected $(7)(6)(5)(4)$ ways.

$\checkmark$ If you want them all to be different, yes, that is so.

> Therefore: $$\frac {(3)(2)(1) +(7)(6)(5)(4)}{10^7}$$

No.  Aside from getting the first two counts above wrong, the counts of tasks performed in series are multiplied.

---

**tl;dr**

What you want to find is the ratio, of the count of ways to select 4 distinct digits of the 7 digits not already used by the extension `452`, to the count of all the ways to select any 4 digits out of all 10 digits with repeatition allowed.

Comment: Then that would be $\frac {(7)(6)(5)(4)}{10^4} $ , boy i bungled that one up...